# How to get Redis Hash Configuration such as Time To Live from application.properties at Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I use

```
    @Value("${cache.host}")
    private String redisHost;

    @Value("${cache.port}")
    private int redisPort;
```

I want to get timeToLive in @RedishHash from application properties. How can get this config?

```
@RedisHash(value = "UserModel", timeToLive = 5)
```

I give manually above however I want to give from application.properties

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if you can do that from application.properties, but u can do it by configuring a RedisCacheManager bean with java based configuration like below :

```
@Bean
public RedisCacheManager RedisCacheManager(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
    Map<String, RedisCacheConfiguration> cacheConfig = new HashMap<String, RedisCacheConfiguration>();
    cacheConfig.put("UserModel", RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
            .entryTtl(Duration.ofHours(5)));
    RedisCacheManager rdisCacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(
            RedisCacheWriter.lockingRedisCacheWriter(redisConnectionFactory),
            RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig(), cacheConfig);
    return rdisCacheManager;
}
```

PS : this method should be in a class with @Configuration annotation

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `@Component` where you are going to take the values from properties

```
@Component
public class RedisHashCustom {
    private static String redisHashValue;

    public static String getRedisHashVaue() {
        return redisHashValue;
    }

    @Value("${application.redis.redishash.value}")
    public void setRedisHashValue(String newRedisHashValue) {
        redisHashValue= newRedisHashValue;
    }
}
```

Then you need to reference as

```
@RedisHash(value = "#{T(com.redis.model.RedisHashCustom).getRedisHashValue() }")
```